# Multiple login in PHP form not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

The else part of my code is working when the password is wrong. However, when password is correct it does not go to the admin.php page. It just stays on the same page.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); // to see if there is error in code

include "connect_to_mysql.php";
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $sql  = mysql_query("select * from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass' LIMIT 3 ") or die( mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $UserName = $data['user'];
    $Password = $data['pass'];
    $type = $data['type'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    if($user==$UserName && $pass==$Password){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name']=$name;
        if($type=='admin'){
            header("location: admin.php");
        }else if($type=='vender1'){
            header("location: vender1.php");
        }

    }
}
?>
```

The database contains: id, name, user, pass, type

So my problem is; after the right password is entered, the same page remains open, but it should open admin.php.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Log In </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  </head>

  <body>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div id="mainWrapper">
   <?php include_once("header.php") ?>
  <div id="pageContent"><br /><br /><br />
   <div align="right" style="margin-right:24px; color:#FF0000">
   <h2>Please Log In To Manage the Inventary</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="login.php">
    <h2 style="padding-right:200px;">User Name:</h2>
      <input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="40" style="height:20px;" />
     <br /><br />
     <h2 style="padding-right:210px;">Password:</h2>
    <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="40" style="height:20px;" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

     <input type="submit" name="log" id="log" value="Log In" />

  </form>
   <p>&nbsp; </p>
  </div>
 <br />
  <br />
 <br />
</div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am stuck here.. Please get me out from here.

Comment: Any error? Like: "Headers are already sent on line ....". If not check what value `$type`has.

Comment: You're code is not save at all btw, don't use `md5` for password hashing, it is easily decrypted. Don't use `mysql` either, it is not supported anymore. Use `pdo` or `mysqli` instead. This way you're code is protected from [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: it seems like you missed to post one closing bracket in your php code

Comment: @LuthandoLoot i think he means that he stays on `index.php`

Comment: if this statement `if($user==$UserName && $pass==$Password)` is false, your code does not do anything, just put an `else` statement there

Comment: try this: $sql=mysql_query("select* from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass'    LIMIT 3 ");
  $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $UserName= $data['user'];   
  $Password= $data['pass'];
  $type= $data['type'];
  $name= $data['name'];
  if($user==$username && $pass==$password){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']=$name;
  if($type=='admin')
  {
         header("location: index.php");
  }
  else if($type=='vender1')
 {
         header("location: vender1.php");
  }
 }
  else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
  }
  ?>

Comment: i have allready put else statement there.. which is this one

Comment: else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
  }

Comment: @deepsingh please look at my first comment, and answer the question. As this is pretty good to know. Second of all, you already had the same question and it was answerd?

Comment: @deepsingh ok i found where it is going wrong. So the check `$user == $Username ....` is returning false then. As you started the session twice after that check, that should already throw an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84794/discussion-between-nytrix-and-deep-singh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test your code. But, I am giving you a sample using mysqli. Hope it helps some.

```
if(isset($_POST["btnLogin"]))
    {
        if(trim($_POST["txtEmail"])!=null && trim($_POST["txtPassword"])!=null)
        {
            $sql=$mysqli->prepare("select * from usermaster where email=?");
            $sql->bind_param("s",$_POST["txtEmail"]);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->bind_result($id,$email,$password,$usertype,$registerdate,$status);
            if($sql->fetch()>0 &&  $_POST["txtPassword"]==$password)
            {
                $_SESSION["userId"]=$id;
                $_SESSION["userName"]=$email;
                $_SESSION["userType"]=$usertype;
                if(strToLower($usertype)=="admin")
                {
                    header("location:admin/manage_users.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    header("location:client/edit_user.php");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $msg="Invalid Username and Password";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $msg="Enter email and password";
        }
    }
```

Comment: send me the code at dt.amanjotkaur@gmail.com if your problem is not solving. I will check it out. @deepsingh

Comment: @Amarjot check ur email yarr

Comment: can u give me ur database script

Comment: come on email.. i will send details of database there

Comment: send me the screenshot of structure

Comment: check ur email with screenshots

Comment: plz come to discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84802/discussion-between-amanjot-and-deep-singh).

Comment: thankew for your help ji.. waheguru bhala kre tuhada

Comment: need ur help.. plz check ur email.... got stucked somewhere..... i have send u email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84863/discussion-between-deep-singh-and-amanjot).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Deep singh,

Try this one,

For hashing function use SHA1 or such encryption methods.

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from login where user= '".$user."' AND pass='".$pass."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Do not require to give limit in query we always get only one record because username and password must be unique.

Not required to check again username and passwords because we write       condition in query right just check number of rows or other options

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0 )
{  
    // store data in session 
    // some actions
}
else
{
    // some actions
}
```

Hope, will help you. Good Luck.. ['}